# Is there a way to throttle git while it's cloning a repo?

Tags: networking, git, bandwidth

Is there a way to tell git to only use so much bandwidth while cloning a repo?

I may have multiple applications - each of which demands different network speeds. Is there a way to tell git to do this? I only want to do it for this session, not every time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there's always [trickle](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=linux%20trickle). Install it, then try something like `trickle -sd 50 git clone`.

`-s` is for standalone mode, `-d` is for download limit, in KB/s